# Reusing React components with different styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, components

In trying to keep React code as reusable as possible, I have often passed CSS classes as a property in React components.  The use case for this is that these components will function exactly the same but can look different depending on where they are in the page.

**Is passing a CSS class as a property in a React component acceptable, or are there better ways of accomplishing the use case above?**

Quick, simplified example:

```
const ToolTipButton = ({ buttonClass, onButtonClick, children }) => (
  <button
    className={buttonClass}
    onClick={onButtonClick}
    data-toggle="pages-tooltip"
    data-placement="top"
    title="Do Something"
  >
    {children}
  </button>
);

<ToolTipButton buttonClass={'ButtonClass1'} onButtonClick={this.doesSomething}/>
<ToolTipButton buttonClass={'ButtonClass2'} onButtonClick={this.doesSomething}>
  // Text and other stuff
</ToolTipButton>
```

Comment: [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/) takes a similar approach. I'd recommend checking them out.

Comment: Almost every component that's built, whether it's semantic, bootstrap, etc... There's typically a className prop that the component accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Css selectors are chainable, so with just pure css, you can have individual styles based on the container. The button component can have a static class such as `tool-tip-button`, and have the stylesheet scope it to the containing component. E.g.

```
.tool-tip-button {
  color: black;
}

.component-a .tool-tip-button {
   color: green;
}

.component-b .tool-tip-button {
   color: red;
}
```

Note that react components can (and are suggested to) have their own individual stylesheet, e.g. `ComponentA.css` and `ComponentB.css`, and simply import them:

```
// ComponentA.js
import './ComponentA.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your class definitions are in scope, passing class names as props is perfectly acceptable. In cases where class definitions are not in scope, the alternative is to pass a style definition object. For example:

```
const ToolTipButton = ({ style, onButtonClick, children }) => (
  <button
    style={style}
    onClick={onButtonClick}
    data-toggle="pages-tooltip"
    data-placement="top"
    title="Do Something"
  >
    {children}
  </button>
);

<ToolTipButton style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} onButtonClick={this.doesSomething}/>
```

Some component libraries (e.g Material UI) allow you to pass both a class name and a style definition object as props. Generally it's better just to use a class name (to avoid defining styles in your js) if possible.